# What type of array sorting algorithm is this?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

What type of sorting algorithm is this? It goes through each index, then gets the minimum value in the rest of the array and swaps.

```
private void Sort(int[] myArray)
{
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i ++)
        {
            var minValue = myArray[i];
            var minIndex = i;

            for(int j = i +1; j< myArray.Length; j++)
            {
                if (myArray[j] < minValue)
                {
                    minIndex = j;
                    minValue = myArray[j];
                }
            }

            var temp = myArray[i];
            myArray[i] = myArray[minIndex];
            myArray[minIndex] = temp;
        }
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, if I do a Google search for "sorting algorithm goes through each index, then gets the minimum value in the rest of the array and swaps", the first link (excluding this question) tells me it's selection sort.

Comment: @Dukeling You'd be surprised (or perhaps not, by now) how often a Google search for the title question or the first line reveals the answer.

Comment: @JimMischel I know that all too well. In this case I thought it useful to point it out since it might not be the type of thing someone would typically expect to get an answer through Google for (it's not one of the many "how do I do X" questions).

Answer (score 2):

It's called [Selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort). As you have already noticed, it selects the minimum element in the remaining list, swaps it in order and repeats until no more elements left.